# Setting environment variables for OpenJDK on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, java, environment-variables, openjdk

I am new to Ubuntu and have programmed in C in the same but java seems  to be a bitof a pain.
This is what -java version looks like

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.3) (6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~11.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

My PATH environment variable is already set to

> /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

but when I try setting the JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH variables I get a warning that says:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel',
but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.JGX9UW': No such file or directory
```

I do not understand what this means.Has it got to do anything with access permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you've already setup it. Try running

```
javac
```

If it displays any message other than `can't find`, you've already done that.

Comment: Well i was being able to compile the .java file so javac was working earlier, i could also see the .class file.It turns out out I didn't have to really set anything more as you said, because doing 'java -cp <path-of-class-file> A.class' did the trick.